# angular 5 calling function to bind class will leads the function to be called infinite times

Tags: angular, angular5

In our `Anuglar 5` project, i invoke a function(isInvalid) to bind a class(`ngClass`), but when the component is shown, and i click any place in the component(credit card paymentpopup overlay), the function is called many many times, someone know why this happens? And is there any solution for this issue?
[image: codes]

[image: web UI]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's well expected .If you have a method in your binding, it will be called every time change detection runs.Angular uses dirty checking to ensure binding stays in sync, so there is at minimum 2 calls per digest.

To fix this, assign the result of the method call to a property and bind to that property instead.

Comment: well, in my case, i can bind a property, but if it is in a ngFor loop, and need to pass a parameter to the function(usually item in the iteration), that means only can bind a method, in that case, how to fix this issue?

Comment: still you can use the property, create a property in item and assign the boolean value to that.